# How to match a string which doesn't contain a dot (.) using regular expression?

Tags: php, string, nginx

How to match a string which doesn't contain a dot (.) using regular expression ?

Comment: if this is for url-rewrite you should remove the php tag and add a ModRewrite tag.

Answer (score 8):

why regex??

```
$str="string_with_no_dots";
if (  strpos ($str,"." ) === FALSE ){
 print "ok, no dots\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class matching anything except the specified, which is done using [] with the ^ operator. And, as the comments say, you want to match it against the beginning (^) and the end ($) or the string so that we check the entire string.

```
^[^.]*$
```

Comment: Since . has no special meaning within a class you don't need the \ there.

Comment: You probably want `^[^.]*$`, to avoid partial matching.

Comment: @Colin Newell: Yes, because this will otherwise match the first character that isn't a `.` and return true.

Comment: I used Kobi's solution, dollar sign is very important there :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression :

if ( !preg_match ( '/\./',$str ,$val ) )

{

print "ok , no dots\n";

}